# Removing elements from an array by value in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

It's a bit fuzzy for me, but I'm trying to create a simple function that takes an array and some arguments and removes the arguments from the array.

For example if I have an array such as `[1,2,3,4]` and the arguments `2,3` it would return `[1,4]` as a result.

This is what I have so far:

```
const removeFromArray = (arr) => {
    let args = Array.from(arguments);

    return arr.filter(function (item) {
        !args.includes(item);
    });
}
```

It doesn't work though. It works if I want to remove all the items from the array, but doesn't if I only go for specific ones.

How can I make this work so that it works even if I'm supplying an argument that is not part of the array (I want it to ignore those) and also if I have strings in the array as well?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: please add the call of the function as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take [rest parameters `...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) for the items to exclude the values.

```js
const removeFromArray = (array, ...items) => array.filter(item => !items.includes(item));

console.log(removeFromArray([1, 2, 3, 4], 1, 4))
```

To use you style, you need to exclude the first item of `arguments`, because this is the array with all items.

```
let args = Array.from(arguments).slice(1);
//                              ^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 2):

In arrow functions the implicit object `arguments` doesn't exist, so declare the function using the keyword `function`, likewise, you need to return the result of the function `includes` within the handler of the function `filter`.

```js
const removeFromArray = function() {
    let [arr, ...args] = Array.from(arguments);
    return arr.filter(function (item) {
        return !args.includes(item);
    });
}

console.log(removeFromArray([1,2,3,4], 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a second parameter for the items you want to have removed.

```
const removeFromArray = (arr, toBeRemoved) => {
    return arr.filter(item => !toBeRemoved.includes(item));
}
```

Example call:

```
const array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
const newArray = removeFromArray(arr, [2, 3])
console.log(newArray) // [1, 4]
```

Answer (score -1):

Stick it to the `Array.prototype`, might use it somewhere else

```
Array.prototype.remove = function(...args) {
  return this.filter(v => !args.includes(v));
}
```